# Pandas CART Model ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cart

I have a data frame 'new_df'. I want to create a CART model that predicts 'Customer Status' using 'Age' and 'Monthly Charge'.

**Data frame (new_df):**

```
    Customer ID Gender  Married Number of Dependents    City    Zip Code    Latitude    Longitude   Offer   Phone Service   ... Tenure in Months    Avg Monthly Long Distance Charges   Avg Monthly GB Download Monthly Charge  Total Charges   Total Refunds   Total Extra Data Charges    Total Long Distance Charges Total Revenue   Totaldata_Binned
0   0002-ORFBO  Female  1   0   Frazier Park    93225   34.827662   -118.999073 None    Yes ... 9   42.390000   16.0    65.60   593.30  0.00    0   381.51  974.81  NaN
1   0003-MKNFE  Male    0   0   Glendale    91206   34.162515   -118.203869 None    Yes ... 9   10.690000   10.0    -4.00   542.40  38.33   10  96.21   610.28  Under 25
2   0004-TLHLJ  Male    0   0   Costa Mesa  92627   33.645672   -117.922613 Offer E Yes ... 4   33.650000   30.0    73.90   280.85  0.00    0   134.60  415.45  NaN
3   0011-IGKFF  Male    1   0   Martinez    94553   38.014457   -122.115432 Offer D Yes ... 13  27.820000   4.0 98.00   1237.85 0.00    0   361.66  1599.51 NaN
4   0013-EXCHZ  Female  1   0   Camarillo   93010   34.227846   -119.079903 None    Yes ... 3   7.380000    11.0    83.90   267.40  0.00    0   22.14   289.54  NaN
...
```

**My code:** CART model

```py
y_train = new_df[['Customer Status']]

# Dummy variables for Marital status
mar_np = np.array(new_df['Age'])
(mar_cat, mar_cat_dict) = stattools.categorical(mar_np, drop=True, dictnames = True)

mar_cat_pd = pd.DataFrame(mar_cat)
X_train = pd.concat((new_df[['Monthly Charge']], mar_cat_pd), axis = 1)

X_names = ['Toddler', 'Child', 'Young Adult', 'Adult', 'Elder']
y_names = [0, 1]

# Maximum leaf node value: 5 (Can be adjusted)
cart01 = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", max_leaf_nodes=5).fit(X_train,y_train)
predIncomeCART = cart01.predict(X_train)
export_graphviz(cart01, out_file = "/Users/christinevu/Downloads/cart01.dot", feature_names=X_names, class_names=y_names)
```

**Error message:** ValueError: Length of feature_names, 5 does not match number of features, 4

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/wv/42dn23fd1cb0czpvqdnb6zw00000gn/T/ipykernel_2542/3906599527.py in <module>
     11 cart01 = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", max_leaf_nodes=5).fit(X,y)
     12 predIncomeCART = cart01.predict(X)
---> 13 export_graphviz(cart01, out_file = "/Users/christinevu/Downloads/cart01.dot", feature_names=X_names, class_names=y_names)

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_export.py in export_graphviz(decision_tree, out_file, max_depth, feature_names, class_names, label, filled, leaves_parallel, impurity, node_ids, proportion, rotate, rounded, special_characters, precision, fontname)
    887             fontname=fontname,
    888         )
--> 889         exporter.export(decision_tree)
    890 
    891         if return_string:

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_export.py in export(self, decision_tree)
    450         if self.feature_names is not None:
    451             if len(self.feature_names) != decision_tree.n_features_in_:
--> 452                 raise ValueError(
    453                     "Length of feature_names, %d does not match number of features, %d"
    454                     % (len(self.feature_names), decision_tree.n_features_in_)

ValueError: Length of feature_names, 5 does not match number of features, 4
```

What does this error message mean and how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, it means that there is one name in `X_names` that is not found in `cart01` when you try to plot it.

Comment: @Laurent I assigned all of the variables to 'X_names' already though. What should I do?

Comment: Try removing one value when assigning to X_names until you find the one that does not belong here, I guess.